# Find if element A is behind element B in HTML DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, z-index

Having an arbitrary pair of colliding elements (by rects) in DOM tree, how to find which one of them is in front and which one is behind?

Given `el1` and `el2` in DOM tree and knowing overlap points using `el1.getBoundingClientRect()` and `el2.getBoundingClientRect()` one can find the overlap rect. 
However having (x,y) point inside overlap rect `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)` returns just one element, which is in front of others at the given point. This element can be neither `el1` nor `el2`.

So if one needs to find if `el1` is in front of  `el2` or vice versa, this approach does not work.

Comment: This question is too broad. Please take a look at the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of the site, particularly this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should add the code of any attempts you've made to solve this yourself to you question as [mcve]s.

Comment: i am asking for general code, it's not about any specific html page and elements

Comment: @progmastery This site is not for general code, not in the general sense. It's to provided solutions to problems that are well defined (not general) and have shown some effort in resolving the issue at first with a minimal set of code already.

Comment: Which you'll realise, if you read those help documents, falls below the standard we expect from people asking questions here. We expect you to try and solve your problem yourself first and then come here if you have any issues. @progmastery

Comment: i have updated the question to reflect a common ways to solve similar problem using `getBoundingClientRect` and `elementFromPoint` functions.

Comment: i hope now my question is much clearer. This  question is non-trivial and tricky

Comment: my answer was wrong before. i think its: use `getComputedStyle` to get computed style object of each element. use style object items like display poperty to get what stacking context the elements in - https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#x43 if elements in same stacking context use `zIndex` from style objects: the one with higher `zIndex` is over the lower `zIndex`. if they are same stack conext and `zIndex` the one later in the DOM is over the one earlier.

Comment: thanks @Barney. so this will require to calculate recursively stacking contexts of all the elements in the DOM using the style rules similarly to what browser does.  Is there a simpler solution, which utilizes only internal properties of DOM elements ?

Comment: @progmastery not as complicated like that. if one element in context # 5 and other in context # 6, other element is over becuase 6 is over 5. you dont need to do all browser does. only check context. or if same context zindex. or if same zindex then position in DOM. im not 100 sure but think so.

Comment: progmastery & @Barney - Simpler to use [`elementsFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) and look in the array for the first element (of the two) that you find. It's "experimental" but the browser support is pretty good.

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/1pnhbsmr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`document.elementsFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint) (note the **`s`**), this will return an Array with all the elements that can be pointed to at these coordinates, ordered by z-index.

```js
onclick = e => {
  console.log( document.elementsFromPoint( e.clientX, e.clientY ) );
}
```

```css
.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.A {
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.B {
  background: green;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.C {
  background: blue;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

You can then filter this Array as you wish to make it contain only some elements and compare their position in that Array, though beware MS implementations return a NodeList, so you may need to reduce it to an Array first.